# Сравнить колонки с учетом значения эпсилон и поместить результат в третью колонку

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Пытаюсь решить такую задачку:
Есть DataFrame с двумя колонками с действительными числами.
Я хочу построить третюю колонку, которая будет принимать значения:

- 1 - если число во второй колонке больше числа в первой
- 0 - если числа в обоих колонках равны
- -1 - если число во второй колонке меньше числа в первой

При сравнении я хочу учитывать некоторый эпсилон, т.к. из за погрешности измерений числа могут быть "примерно равны".

Написал такой код и он вроде как работает как мне надо:

```
columns = ['col1', 'col2']
data = [[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 1.0]]
epsilon = 0.01
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df['is_up'] = np.where((df['col2'] - df['col1'] > epsilon),1, np.nan)
df['is_down'] = np.where((df['col2'] - df['col1'] < - epsilon),-1, np.nan)
df['is_equal'] =  np.where((abs(df['col2'] - df['col1']) < epsilon),0, np.nan)

df['col3'] = df[['is_up','is_down','is_equal']].replace('None','').sum(1)
```

Результат:

```
-----------------------------------------------
col1 | col2 | is_up | is_down | is_equal | col3
-----------------------------------------------
1.0  |1.0   |NaN    |NaN      |0.0       |0.0
1.0  |2.0   |1.0    |NaN      |NaN       |1.0
2.0  |1.0   |NaN    |-1.0     |NaN       |-1.0
```

Однако меня не покидает ощущение, что можно сделать проще, понятнее и быстрее.  Направьте на путь истинный, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Могу предложить как мне кажется более понятное на вид решение, но с использованием дополнительной библиотеки `Numba`. Декоратор `vectorize` из этой библиотеки позволяет работать с векторами (массивами) значений так, как будто это обычные числа (и делает это очень быстро).

```py
from numba import vectorize

@vectorize
def compare_with_epsilon(x, y, epsilon):
  if x - y > epsilon:
    return 1
  elif x - y < -epsilon:
    return -1
  else:
    return 0

df['col3'] = compare_with_epsilon(df['col2'].values, df['col1'].values, epsilon)
```

В принципе, можно было бы обойтись и без `vectorize`, если сделать параллельный перебор в цикле значений переданных на вход функции массивов, но с таким декоратором и код понятнее и работать должно довольно быстро.

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь `np.isclose()` и `np.sign()`:

```
df['col3'] = np.where(
    np.isclose(df['col1'], df['col2'], atol=epsilon), 
    0, 
    np.sign(df['col2'] - df['col1']))
```

Comment: Так и знал, что в numpy на все случаи жизни есть функции. Учиться и учиться ещё :)